# No page number in first page

Tags: libreoffice

I am writing a document and it is required that the first page (title page) has no page number and the second page starts with page 2. I don't know how to remove the footed only in page 1 and leaving the footer in the rest of the pages as is. Can anyone maybe help? 
Many thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First, make a copy of your document for safety purposes!

Please set so called 'Title pages':

```
Menu format -> Insert title pages  *convert existing pages to title pages
```

And while setting page numbers in footnote:

```
Menu insert -> Field -> Others -> Document -> Page -> Page numbers -> Offset.
```

[image]

Set it to requested value: 1

Answer (score 45):

I am assuming that you already know how to set page numbers to your document.

Removing page number on the first page and starting page number from the second page is even easier than the accepted answer.

Click on Format menu and select Title page.

[image]

You will now be presented with a 'Title pages' dialog box. Under 'Page numbering' heading, select the option 'Reset Page Numbering after title pages'. You may choose the number of title pages that you don't want to have the page number.

[image: Reset title page numbering]

Comment: This answer works on me on LibreOffice 3.5.2.2. My first page (cover page) has no page number, and page after it has number starting from 1. Excellent.

Comment: Does not work for me.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me in LibreOffice 6.0.6.2.

Answer (score 4):

The previous answers are definitely the easiest way to fix your problem.  The options involving Title pages are relatively new.

The "old" way is more generic and will solve many other problems as well.

One of the greatest strengths of LibreOffice writer is its concept of styles.  Styles are sets of formatting options that can be applied to individual or multiple characters, paragraphs, lists, frames, or pages.  When you assign a style to one of these "objects", it applies the formatting from the style, but also remembers that the object is formatted in that style.

Subsequently, if you change the definition of the style, every object that has that style may be updated - either manually or automatically, if auto update is selected for that style.  It's a great way to uniformly change everything that should look the same in your document at one time - like changing all subtitles to have a different font or point size.

In this case, you could define and apply a page style for the title page that has no page number.  You can also change anything else about this page without affecting the other pages.

You can open the styles dialog by pressing F11.

Styles are useful for all sorts of other things like making left pages different from right pages and making all your body text a particular font and size without changing special text like headings.

If you haven't used styles before, it takes some getting used to, but it's well worth the effort.  There's a lot more to it as well.  Styles are very powerful.

Bruce Byfield writes clearly on the subject and on several other writer subjects.

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7203

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7488

Solveig Haugland is also very clear on many writer topics.

http://openoffice.blogs.com/

Comment: WOW i knew about text style named style managemend in Word but about page styling.. This is MUCH MORE POWERFULL ANSWER. Im Favoriting question also for getting such chance of this answer appearance posibility.

Answer (score 4):

If you set the offset to "-1," the second page (the one after the title page) will show up as "page 1" in the page number field.

Answer (score 1):

Formatting the first page as "First page" using F11 > Page Style, then inserting a page counting field on the 2nd page footer and finally setting the offset to -1 also works.