# Write a Footnote Per page

Tags: 12.04, libreoffice

I need to write a footnote per page in my document (not a footer which is the same throughout document). How do I do that? 
Note that some page have no footnote(s)

Comment: Well that's a nice Ubuntu question, isn't it?

Comment: I found same question on Footer while in search and it was nicely answered not locked...so I guess Yes :)
http://askubuntu.com/questions/101838/no-page-number-in-first-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A footer is defined in it's page style. If you want a different footer for each page, you also need to have a style for every page. See [this](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Defining_Different_Headers_and_Footers) help page for more information.

Note that you can also insert fields that vary based on, let's say, current page number or current chapter title. Creating a page style for each page seems a bit cumbersome.